# Is it possible to change Calendar.app's color scheme to give today a more distinct background color?

Tags: macos, calendar

I'm running 10.8.5. I use Calendar.app pretty heavily (it's hooked up to the Exchange server at work) and my only continual beef is that the current day doesn't stand out enough visually.

[image: Screen shot]

I don't see any preferences to tweak this. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this, either through the app's visual or hidden preferences.

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/ical.html